# Material-UI: build the menu/submenu as http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu

Tags: material-ui

I would like to build the menu as the one in Material-UI.

I am using the menuItems to generate the submenu.

```
<MenuItem anchorOrigin = {{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom', animated : 'false'}}
                    menuItems={[ <MenuItem primaryText="Show Level 2" />]}
                > Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
```

The only thing I need is alway keep the submenu open.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by always open?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I found a way to do it by using multiple Menu Component and depend on the state to show the submenu.

Comment: @TrongPhan can you explain how you did this?

Comment: I used one Menu as Parent, one Menu as Submenu and handle event in the Parent Menu to show/hide the Submenu. Hope it helps.